# Symfony2 Form - Embed forms and event listeners

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form "AddressType" with an event listener that works as expected when instantiated alone. Here is the code.

```
namespace Nc\ClientsBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Nc\ClientsBundle\Form\EventListener\AddCityFieldSubscriber;

class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('street')
            ->add('number', 'text')
            ->add('complement')
            ->add('district')
            ->add('state', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'ClientsBundle:State', 
                'property' => 'name',
            ));
        $subscriber = new AddCityFieldSubscriber($builder->getFormFactory());
        $builder->addEventSubscriber($subscriber);
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Nc\ClientsBundle\Entity\Address',
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'addresstype';
    }
}


<?php

namespace Nc\ClientsBundle\Form\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Event\DataEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class AddCityFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $factory;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory)
    {
        $this->factory = $factory;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        // Tells the dispatcher that we want to listen on the form.pre_set_data
        // event and that the preSetData method should be called.
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA  => 'preSetData');
    }

    public function preSetData(DataEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // During form creation setData() is called with null as an argument
        // by the FormBuilder constructor. We're only concerned with when
        // setData is called with an actual Entity object in it (whether new,
        // or fetched with Doctrine). This if statement let's us skip right
        // over the null condition.
        if (null === $data) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$data->getCity()) {

            $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('city_selector', 'city', null, array(
                'choices'   => array('' => '--  Selecione um estado  --'),
                'required'  => true,
                'expanded'  => false,
                'multiple'  => false,
            )));

        } else {

            $city = $data->getCity();
            $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('city_selector', 'city', null, array(
                'choices'   => array($city->getId() => $city->getName()),
                'required'  => true,
                'expanded'  => false,
                'multiple'  => false,
            )));
        }

    }

}

<?php

namespace Nc\ClientsBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Nc\ClientsBundle\Form\DataTransformer\CityToIdTransformer;

class CitySelectorType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    private $om;

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $om
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
    {
        $this->om = $om;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $transformer = new CityToIdTransformer($this->om);
        $builder->prependNormTransformer($transformer);
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'invalid_message' => 'Selecione um estado e uma cidade.',
        );
    }

    public function getParent(array $options)
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'city_selector';
    }
}

<?php

namespace Nc\ClientsBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Nc\ClientsBundle\Entity\City;

class CityToIdTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ObjectManager
     */
    private $om;

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $om
     */
    public function __construct(ObjectManager $om)
    {
        $this->om = $om;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms an object (city) to a integer (id).
     *
     * @param  City|null $city
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($city)
    {
        if ($city === null) {
            return '';
        }

        return $city->getId();

    }

    /**
     * Transforms a string (id) to an object (city).
     *
     * @param  string $id
     * @return City|null
     * @throws TransformationFailedException if object (city) is not found.
     */
    public function reverseTransform($id)
    {
        if (!$id) {
            return null;
        }

        $city = $this->om
            ->getRepository('ClientsBundle:City')
            ->findOneBy(array('id' => $id))
        ;

        if (null === $city) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
                'An city with id "%s" does not exist!',
                $id
            ));
        }

        return $city;
    }
}
```

What happens is that when I try to embed this form into the "ClientType" form, the "city" field is not rendered.

```
namespace Nc\ClientsBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class ClientType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('type', 'choice', array(
            'choices'   => array('1' => 'Comum', '2' => 'Parceiro'),
            'expanded'  => true,
            'multiple'  => false,
            'required'  => true,
        ));
        $builder->add('contactInfo', new ContactInfoType(), array('label' => ' '));
        $builder->add('address', new AddressType(), array('label' => ' '));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Nc\ClientsBundle\Entity\Client',
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'clienttype';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you try to embed city field and entity does not have city value filled, method $form->getData() returns null, so city field won't render at this case, because "if" statement always returns false (preSetData function in the subscriber class)
First of all we gotta check if city is filled, if so add corresponding form field, otherwise add blank field (or whatever).

Here are some code snippets:

1. Add city field if its value is filled

   ```
   public function preSetData(DataEvent $event)
   {
       $data = $event->getData();
       $form = $event->getForm();

       if (!($data instanceof Address) || !$data->getCity()) {
           return;
       }

       $city = $data->getCity();
       $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('city_selector', 'city', null, array(
           'choices'   => array($city->getId() => $city->getName()),
           'required'  => true,
           'expanded'  => false,
           'multiple'  => false,
       )));
   }
   ```
2. Add blank city field if its value is not filled (postSetData triggers just after from data is set)

   ```
   public function postSetData(DataEvent $event)
   {
       $form = $event->getForm();

       if (!$form->has('city_selector')) {
           $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('city_selector', 'city', null, array(
               'choices'   => array('' => '--  Selecione um estado  --'),
               'required'  => true,
               'expanded'  => false,
               'multiple'  => false,
           )));
       }
   }
   ```
3. We also have to register postSetData event

   ```
   public static function getSubscribedEvents()
   {
       return array(
           FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA   => 'preSetData',
           FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA  => 'postSetData'
       );
   }
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: Thank you! Ill try to follow your recomendation, hope my english is not that bad.